# How do you solve a system of PDEs in canonical form?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, partial-derivative, canonical-transformation

Suppose you wish to solve a system of $n$ PDEs, which can be expressed in vector form as
$$
A \boldsymbol{u}_x + B \boldsymbol{u}_y = \boldsymbol{c} \hspace{10mm} (*_1)
$$
where
$$
A  = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & \dots & a_{1n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & \dots & a_{nn} \end{pmatrix} \hspace{20mm} B = \begin{pmatrix} b_{11} & \dots & b_{1n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ b_{n1} & \dots & b_{nn} \end{pmatrix} \\
\boldsymbol{c} = \begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ \vdots \\ c_n \end{pmatrix} \hspace{20mm} \boldsymbol{u} = \begin{pmatrix} u_x^{(1)} \\ \vdots \\ u_x^{(n)} \end{pmatrix}
$$
The method for solving such a system is to multiply through $(*_1)$ by $A^{-1}$ (to the left of each term) so that it is in the form
$$
\boldsymbol{u}_x + D \boldsymbol{u}_y = \boldsymbol{d} \hspace{10mm} (*_2)
$$
where $D = A^{-1} B$ and $\boldsymbol{d} = A^{-1} \boldsymbol{c}$.

We then diagonalize the matrix $D$, expressing it in the form
$$
\Lambda := P^{-1} D P \hspace{10mm} (*_3)
$$
where $P$ is the matrix who's columns are the Eigenvectors of the matrix $D$, and define the transformation
$$
\boldsymbol{u} = P \boldsymbol{v} \hspace{10mm} (*_4)
$$

Then, through substituting in $(*_3)$ and $(*_4)$, the equation $(*_2)$ can be expressed in the form
$$
\boldsymbol{v}_x + \Lambda \boldsymbol{v}_y = \boldsymbol{q}
$$
where
$$
\boldsymbol{q} = P^{-1} \boldsymbol{d} - P^{-1} P_x \boldsymbol{v} - P^{-1} D P_y \boldsymbol{v}
$$
(I believe that this is known at the *canonical form* of the system of equations)

This is where I no longer know how to continue with this method. From this point, where we have a new system of equations in canonical form, how do we obtain a solution the the system of PDEs?